# How do I combine Pandas dataframes by looking at dates in one dataframe that fall within a date range in another dataframe?

Tags: python, date, pandas

I have two dataframes that have employee data as below. One data file has employee data including dates on which employees were sick, and the other data file has dates on which employees worked (i.e. presented as date ranges).
I would like to combine the two files (hopefully in pandas) by looking at where the "sick day" for a particular employee falls in a "work range". For example, in image/data below, employee 1 was sick on 11/25/2015, 12/23/2015, and 10/12/2015. These fall in the "work ranges" 11/21/2015 - 11/29/2015, 12/21/2015 - 12/29/2015, and 10/9/2015 - 10/17/2015, respectively.

EMPLOYEE WORK DATES DATA:

```html
╔══════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ Employee ║   datein   ║  dateout   ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║ 11/21/2015 ║ 11/29/2015 ║
║        2 ║ 12/9/2015  ║ 12/14/2015 ║
║        3 ║ 11/10/2015 ║ 11/19/2015 ║
║        4 ║ 11/11/2015 ║ 11/17/2015 ║
║        5 ║ 11/30/2015 ║ 12/8/2015  ║
║        1 ║ 12/21/2015 ║ 12/29/2015 ║
║        2 ║ 1/7/2016   ║ 1/12/2016  ║
║        3 ║ 12/10/2015 ║ 12/19/2015 ║
║        4 ║ 12/10/2015 ║ 12/16/2015 ║
║        5 ║ 12/30/2015 ║ 1/7/2016   ║
║        1 ║ 10/9/2015  ║ 10/17/2015 ║
║        2 ║ 10/27/2015 ║ 11/1/2015  ║
║        3 ║ 9/28/2015  ║ 10/7/2015  ║
║        4 ║ 9/29/2015  ║ 10/5/2015  ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

EMPLOYEE SICK DATES DATA:

```html
╔══════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ Employee ║  sickDate  ║ sickness  ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║        1 ║ 11/25/2015 ║ flu       ║
║       10 ║ 11/21/2015 ║ hd        ║
║       21 ║ 9/20/2015  ║ other     ║
║        1 ║ 12/23/2015 ║ other     ║
║        4 ║ 12/13/2015 ║ vacationx ║
║        7 ║ 7/21/2015  ║ cough     ║
║        3 ║ 10/1/2015  ║ rash      ║
║        4 ║ 10/5/2015  ║ other     ║
║        5 ║ 1/7/2016   ║ eyex      ║
║        2 ║ 12/12/2015 ║ tanx      ║
║        1 ║ 10/12/2015 ║ fatiguex  ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

CONSOLIDATED DATA:

```html
╔══════════╦════════════╦════════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ Employee ║   datein   ║  dateout   ║  sickDate  ║ sickness  ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬════════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║        1 ║ 11/21/2015 ║ 11/29/2015 ║ 11/25/2015 ║ flu       ║
║        2 ║ 12/9/2015  ║ 12/14/2015 ║ 12/12/2015 ║ tanx      ║
║        3 ║ 11/10/2015 ║ 11/19/2015 ║            ║           ║
║        4 ║ 11/11/2015 ║ 11/17/2015 ║            ║           ║
║        5 ║ 11/30/2015 ║ 12/8/2015  ║            ║           ║
║        1 ║ 12/21/2015 ║ 12/29/2015 ║ 12/23/2015 ║ other     ║
║        2 ║ 1/7/2016   ║ 1/12/2016  ║            ║           ║
║        3 ║ 12/10/2015 ║ 12/19/2015 ║            ║           ║
║        4 ║ 12/10/2015 ║ 12/16/2015 ║ 12/13/2015 ║ vacationx ║
║        5 ║ 12/30/2015 ║ 1/7/2016   ║ 1/7/2016   ║ eyex      ║
║        1 ║ 10/9/2015  ║ 10/17/2015 ║ 10/12/2015 ║ fatiguex  ║
║        2 ║ 10/27/2015 ║ 11/1/2015  ║            ║           ║
║        3 ║ 9/28/2015  ║ 10/7/2015  ║ 10/1/2015  ║ rash      ║
║        4 ║ 9/29/2015  ║ 10/5/2015  ║ 10/5/2015  ║ other     ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩════════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

---

How do I do that in pandas or python? (Thank you for your help!)

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this data to `pd.DataFrame( ... )` as **df1** 
and `set_index('Employee')`

```html
╔══════════╦════════════╦════════════╗
║ Employee ║   datein   ║  dateout   ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬════════════╣
║        1 ║ 11/21/2015 ║ 11/29/2015 ║
║        2 ║ 12/9/2015  ║ 12/14/2015 ║
║        3 ║ 11/10/2015 ║ 11/19/2015 ║
║        4 ║ 11/11/2015 ║ 11/17/2015 ║
║        5 ║ 11/30/2015 ║ 12/8/2015  ║
║        1 ║ 12/21/2015 ║ 12/29/2015 ║
║        2 ║ 1/7/2016   ║ 1/12/2016  ║
║        3 ║ 12/10/2015 ║ 12/19/2015 ║
║        4 ║ 12/10/2015 ║ 12/16/2015 ║
║        5 ║ 12/30/2015 ║ 1/7/2016   ║
║        1 ║ 10/9/2015  ║ 10/17/2015 ║
║        2 ║ 10/27/2015 ║ 11/1/2015  ║
║        3 ║ 9/28/2015  ║ 10/7/2015  ║
║        4 ║ 9/29/2015  ║ 10/5/2015  ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩════════════╝
```

Then put this data to `pd.DataFrame( ... )` as **df2** and `set_index('Employee')`

```html
╔══════════╦════════════╦═══════════╗
║ Employee ║  sickDate  ║ sickness  ║
╠══════════╬════════════╬═══════════╣
║        1 ║ 11/25/2015 ║ flu       ║
║       10 ║ 11/21/2015 ║ hd        ║
║       21 ║ 9/20/2015  ║ other     ║
║        1 ║ 12/23/2015 ║ other     ║
║        4 ║ 12/13/2015 ║ vacationx ║
║        7 ║ 7/21/2015  ║ cough     ║
║        3 ║ 10/1/2015  ║ rash      ║
║        4 ║ 10/5/2015  ║ other     ║
║        5 ║ 1/7/2016   ║ eyex      ║
║        2 ║ 12/12/2015 ║ tanx      ║
║        1 ║ 10/12/2015 ║ fatiguex  ║
╚══════════╩════════════╩═══════════╝
```

Finally, `df = df1.join(df2).reset_index()`

Comment: Sorry this is not working when I apply it to my "bigger" data file. I have put the data on Google docs. 2 tabs. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gyw2if41MU8wSbjto6rQfLW9x68_kqTOzsqcZ-laSqA/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Consider an inner and outer [pandas merge](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) approach. Below assumes dates are in `datetime` formats which may require conversion from string objects:

```
workdf['datein'] = pd.to_datetime(workdf['datein'])
workdf['dateout'] = pd.to_datetime(workdf['dateout'])
sickdf['sickDate'] = pd.to_datetime(sickdf['sickDate'])

# INNER MERGE ON BOTH DFs WHERE SICK DAYS REPEAT FOR MATCHING EMPLOYEE ROW IN WORK DAYS
mergedf = pd.merge(workdf, sickdf, on='Employee', how="inner")

# OUTER MERGE TO KEEP ALL WORK DAY RECORDS WITH FILTERED SICK DAYS DATA SET
finaldf = pd.merge(mergedf[(mergedf['sickDate'] - mergedf['datein'] >= 0) &
                           (mergedf['dateout'] - mergedf['sickDate'] >= 0)],
                   workdf, on=['Employee', 'datein', 'dateout'], how="outer")

finaldf = finaldf.sort(['Employee','datein','dateout']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Result

```
#    Employee     datein      dateout     sickDate   sickness
#0          1 2015-10-09   2015-10-17   2015-10-12   fatiguex
#1          1 2015-11-21   2015-11-29   2015-11-25        flu
#2          1 2015-12-21   2015-12-29   2015-12-23      other
#3          2 2015-10-27   2015-11-01          NaT        NaN
#4          2 2015-12-09   2015-12-14   2015-12-12       tanx
#5          2 2016-01-07   2016-01-12          NaT        NaN
#6          3 2015-09-28   2015-10-07   2015-10-01       rash
#7          3 2015-11-10   2015-11-19          NaT        NaN
#8          3 2015-12-10   2015-12-19          NaT        NaN
#9          4 2015-09-29   2015-10-05   2015-10-05      other
#10         4 2015-11-11   2015-11-17          NaT        NaN
#11         4 2015-12-10   2015-12-16   2015-12-13  vacationx
#12         5 2015-11-30   2015-12-08          NaT        NaN
#13         5 2015-12-30   2016-01-07   2016-01-07       eyex
```

Comment: Sorry this is not working when I apply it to my "bigger" data file. I have put the data on Google docs. 2 tabs. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Gyw2if41MU8wSbjto6rQfLW9x68_kqTOzsqcZ-laSqA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What error do you receive? What's not working? Be sure to adjust actual field names. Consider also removing the Year, Month, Day, MonthNo columns as pandas retains that in datetime fields.